# Counting Word Frequency in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I have a list of lists:

```
list1 =  [['This','could','be','heaven'] ,['This','could','be','hell'],['heaven','or','hell','i','like','it']]
```

I want to produce an ordered dictionary of word frequency where the word is the key and the value is the number of times it occurred in the entire list e.g.:

```
{'could': 2, 'hell':2, 'this':2,'be':2,'heaven':2,'like':1,'i':1,'it':1,'or':1}
```

I think I should be using set() + count() + dictionary comprehension; something like this:

```
res = {idx : list1[idx] for idx in set(list1)} 

print(res)
```

I know I should be able to do it one line but I need some help

Comment: do you absolutely need a one-liner answer? Or multiple lines of code will do as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a one liner:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(x for sublist in list1 for x in sublist)
```

or a multi-liner without any imports:

```
counts = {}
for sublist in list1:
    for x in sublist:
        if x in counts:
            counts[x] += 1
        else:
            counts[x] = 0
```

though I recommend using Counter for readability.